# R - conditionally modify a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to check to see if a dataframe has a certain number of columns, and then conditionally modify the dataframe based on the number of columns it has.

If I try

```
ifelse(ncol(Table1)=="desired number of columns",Table1[,ColumnsSelected],Table1[,ColumnsSelected2]))
```

I get Table 1 back, but only one column, and it looks weird. Is there a way that I can change this to make it so that I can return a dataframe with the desired columns based on the number of columns in the dataframe?

I have roughly 700 tables that have 2 types of formatting that I would prefer not to have to individually scan to reformat.

Please advise

Comment: I think `ifelse` function loop through rows, so it is better to use `if`.. `esle`. For example, `if (ncol(Table1)=="desired number of columns"){Table1[,ColumnsSelected]}else{Table1[,ColumnsSelected2]}` If you have many tables just loop through all tables.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I was looking for.